# Block Screen does not work with multiple AJAX calls

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred, jquery-blockui

I have a button called "Submit Assessment". There i am trying to save image using ajax call and depend on the result another ajax call will be executed in order to post data to server.
Coding structure as follows

**JS Code:**

```
var isPostedImage=false;
Submit Click function
{
   //call to screen lock function
   PostAssessmentData();
}

function PostAssessmentData()
{
   isPostedImage=PostImage();
   if (isPostedImage)
   {
      //AJAX call to post data to server
      async:false;
   }
}

PostImage=function()
{
  //AJAX call to save Image in server
  async:false;
  //if it is successful 
  isPostedImage=true;
}
```

My question is i called to lock screen function as first step. But screen does not lock until above ajax calls have been executed. I have make those async :false as well. I think deferred object is good concept to this. But i don't know how to use deferred object concept in this scenario.

Can someone please help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you saying the ajax call inside `PostAssessmentData ()` is executed well before the ajax call inside `Postimage()` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Freezing the screen until the chained ajax calls is complete is done like this

**What I have done:**

- showing a loader image like spinner on screen before making ajax calls.
- The second ajax call will be executed inside the success callback of the first ajax call, so that the response received from first call is sent to second call.
- Once all the calls are completed hide the spinner from the screen, allowing the user to interact with the screen.

**JS Code:**

```
$('#loading').hide();

function p1() {
   return $.post("/echo/html/", {
    html: "Happy"
    });
}

function p2(firstCallData) {
    var newData = firstCallData + " Coding :)";
    return $.post("/echo/html/", {
       html: newData
    });
}

function clickHandler() {
    $('#loading').show();
    $.when(p1()).then(function (firstCallResults) {
        console.log(firstCallResults);
        $.when(p2(firstCallResults)).then(function (secondCallResults)     {
             console.log(secondCallResults);
             alert("All ajax calls processed.\n" + secondCallResults);
             $('#loading').hide();
        });
    });
}

$(function () {
   $("#go").click(clickHandler);
});
```

[Live Demo @ JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/A4FVU/16/)

*Note:Above solution is based on a generic idea and hence this solution should not to be considered as a final solution*